# Compress JSON object send from c# to Javascript POST -(performance improvement )

Tags: javascript, c#, json, performance, compression

[image]

[image]

We are sending a large amount of data (almost 4MB - 5MB depending upon the location) from c# to javascript and using .xslt page displaying the list page
I am thinking the problem resides in the JSON object which we are sending from c# to javascript 
This has been legacy code,

//C#

```
public JsonResult GetData(string requestId, int browserWidth)
        {
        
        ClassViewModel classViewModel = GetHotelModel(requestId);
        ClassJsonData cJsonData = new ClassJsonData();
        cJsonData.IsError = false;
        cJsonData.XmlData = classViewModel.XmlData;
        cJsonData.RegionXML = classViewModel.RegionXML;
        cJsonData.StarCategoryXml = classViewModel.StarCategoryXml;
        cJsonData.TotalRecordCount = classViewModel.TotalRecordCount;
        
        return new JsonResult { Data = cJsonData, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
        //After executing this statement, the time taken to show javascript alert message is almost 3-4 mins
        }
```

//javascript

```
if (requestid != undefined && requestid > 0) {
                AjaxGlobalHandler.PostData('/Shop/GetData', JSON.stringify({ requestId: requestid, browserWidth: $(window).width() }), null, function (result) {
                    alert("hello I am here now !!!")//to show this alert msg ,taking almost 3-4 mins 
                    if (result.IsError) {
                        ErrorMessageDisplay(result);
                    }
                    else {
                       
                        DisplayShopList(result);
                    }
                }, null);
            }
```

**Is there any compression method we could use to improve the performance? 

or any suggestions?**

Comment: compress it? unsure how you will compress it.  Are you positive it is not the backend taking forever to generate the JSON? You are sending down gigs of JSON?

Comment: @epascarello yes I am positive bcz I am checking through the debugger, we have control till return JsonResult

Comment: And what is this MASSIVE JSON size?

Comment: I have updated the question, the size would be approx 4 - 5MB depending upon the search location

Comment: Compression take time to compress and uncompress.  So the transfer rate, size of data, and compression time all has to be considered.  If you are sending an image it probably will only reduce size by a very small amount to the time to compress/uncompress will be larger than the time saved.  But if you are sending a text documents you may get a very large amount of compression and you will save time.

Comment: 5MB is not huge.... It could be the parser. Simple way to check is fetch it as text instead of JSON and see how long it would take to get it.

Comment: Guys, I have updated the question , content download is taking time? or my javascript control is somewhere else when we get a response or in GoogleMaps where is taking more time to complete